# Type provides no match for the signature using withStyles

Tags: typescript, material-ui

While trying to convert my React App to typescript, I keep getting the error below and for the life of me I cannot figure out what it's saying. The app works fine in plain JS. I'm using `material-ui@next`

```
 TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof ApplicationMenu' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<AppMenuProps & WithStyles<"root" | "flex" | "menuButton" | "appBar" | "loginButton">>'.
  Type 'typeof ApplicationMenu' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<AppMenuProps & WithStyles<"root" | "flex" | "menuButton" | "appBar" | "loginBu...'.
    Type 'typeof ApplicationMenu' provides no match for the signature '(props: AppMenuProps & WithStyles<"root" | "flex" | "menuButton" | "appBar" | "loginButton"> & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

The code that produces this error is below

```
export interface AppMenuProps {
    classes: Record<string, string | undefined>
}

const styles = (theme : Theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    flex: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginLeft: -12,
        marginRight: 20,
    },

    appBar: {
        background: theme.palette.common.black,
        color: theme.palette.common.white,
    },

    loginButton: {
        color: theme.palette.common.white
    }
});

class ApplicationMenu extends Component<AppMenuProps, {}> {

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <AppBar position="static" classes={{root: classes.appBar}}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="primary" aria-label="Menu">
                            <MenuIcon/>
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography type="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
                            Supportworks Dashboard
                        </Typography>
                        <Button classes={{root: classes.loginButton}}>Login</Button>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ApplicationMenu)
```

Comment: what version of typescript are you using?

Comment: Version 2.6.2 according to package.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the TypeScript guide, particularly the section on withStyles (links redacted):

> Class components are a little more cumbersome. Due to a [current limitation in TypeScript's decorator support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881), `withStyles` can't be used as a class decorator. Instead, we decorate a class component...

You would need to do something like this:

```js
import { WithStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

export interface AppMenuProps {
    classes: Record<string, string | undefined>
}
    
const styles = (theme : Theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    flex: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginLeft: -12,
        marginRight: 20,
    },
    appBar: {
        background: theme.palette.common.black,
        color: theme.palette.common.white,
    },
    loginButton: {
        color: theme.palette.common.white
    }
});

const ApplicationMenu = decorate(
  class extends React.Component<AppMenuProps & WithStyles<'root' | 'flex' | 'menuButton' | 'appBar' | 'loginButton'>> {
    render() {
      // ...
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I cannot edit at the moment because the pending edits queue is full, but the "TypeScript guide" links lead to a dubious site. Could someone redact these links (or even better, find the real ones)?